# Пентамино (необходимы алгоритмы для поиска решений)

Tags: алгоритм

Есть игра [Пентамино](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CF%E5%ED%F2%E0%EC%E8%ED%EE).

В моём случае необходимо фигуру из 60 квадратиков разбить на 12 пентамино различных типов. Может кто-то уже решал подобную задачу? Код не нужен. Нужны названия алгоритмов, которыми вы пользовались или другие полезные подсказки.

Comment: сказала бы по простому СТРОИЧКАААА! =) все знают строичку и тетрис... хотя наверно школоте уже не понять =)

Comment: @Gorets, а у меня, в своё время, именно "Пентамино" на коробочке было написано)

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой алгоритм - перебор. Заготавливаем матрицу 5 на 12 (или 6 на 10. Если в ячейке записан 0 - значит никем не занята, если число больше нуля - значит принадлежит фигурке с данным номером. А теперь - ПЕРЕБОР - берем очередную фигурку и пробуем ее приложить в каждую клеточку в четырех положениях если не прикладыватся - берем следующую. Если приложилась - пробуем следующую фигурку. Если все фигурки использованы - нашлось решение.

Способ выглядит плохо. Фигурок 48 (12 умножить на 4), клеток 60. Каждая фигурка теоретически может быть в любой клетке (теоретически). поэтому получаем 48 в 60 степени (а это порядка 7 на 10 в 100). Поэтому нужно применять следующие улучшения - не ставить новую фигурку в такую клетку, что она не будет иметь общей границы с существующими фигурками (самая первая обязательно занимает угловую клетку). Для первой фигурки будет максимум 4 варианта, а для последующих - 10-15 (нужно сидеть и уточнять). А это уже даст сильно меньше 4*(44 в 15) - то есть, несколько сот тысяч. А это уже легко перебрать.

Можно ещё чуточку улучшить. Разложить перебор на две части. В первой части пытаемся собрать нижние 2 (3 или 4) линии. То есть, не пробовать варианты, когда очередная фигурка располагается выше данной линии (если часть фигурки торчит - ничего страшного). А потом, для каждого с найденных вариантов уже искать полное решение. Или ещё лучше - найти такие решения, где собранные участки не пересекаются по фигуркам. Соответственно будет низ и верх, и нужно будет заполнить середину. Если заполнять не более 3 линий, а прямоугольник 6 на 10, то перекрытий не будет (это легко доказать).

И на остаток - почитать статью на [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/114457/).

P.S. Вышеуказанное правильно, если говорим, о одностороннем пентамино. Если фигурки разрешается переворачивать - вариантов будет больше.

Answer (score 0):

Мой вариант:

1. Надо иметь набор исходных фигурок (12 шт по условию)(а то без них задание упрощается =) )
2. Дальше надо условие, что из этих 12 штук РЕАЛЬНО можно сложить "фигуру из 60 квадратиков" - что это за фигура?))
3. Рандомить пока не сложатся как надо =) или думать над алгоритмом по выборке подходящих фигур... но пока нечего не понятно =(

Comment: фигуры могут быть абсолютно разные))

Comment: мне кажется это упрощает задание, потому что можно, например, 60/12 =5 - это равных частей, (т.е. можно вместить 12 фигур равных размеров по 5 квадратов), нам же надо что бы они были не равные, тогда просто меняем их размер на 2,3,5,7,8 - и выводим результат...

Comment: они должны быть рвные, думала, что это понятно из задания :) В википедии представлены 12 возможных фигурок, из которых необходимо собрать итоговую фигуру (поданную на входе).

Comment: ну так там же на вики и есть тебе нужные алгоритмы...

Answer (score 0):

Данный вид задач относится к динамическому программированию по профилю. Более подробно можно почитать [тут](http://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8E). Могу сразу сказать, что сама по себе методика является достаточно сложной и с первого раза вникнуть будет крайней сложно.